# Convert time (without date) to UTC time in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a string of time I need to parse that's currently in a 12 hour clock format. Some examples are the following:

- `11:30 PM`
- `07:00 AM`

These times are currently in eastern time zone. What's the best way to convert those strings to a string that contains the UTC equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

val fmtFromLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a z") // z parses time zone
val fmtToGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a")

def toGmt(t: String): String = fmtToGmt.format(fmtFromLocal.parse(s + " EST"))
```

Unfortunately, this fails when the local timezone is not GMT, as .parse() returns a local time.

Corrected:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.{Date, TimeZone}

val localTz = TimeZone.getDefault()
val currentOffset = localTz.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis)
val fmtFromLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a z") // z parses time zone
val fmtToGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a")
def toGmt(t: String): String = {
  val time = fmtFromLocal.parse(t).getTime()
  val timeUtc = time + currentOffset
  fmtToGmt.format(new Date(timeUtc))
}
```

(Not tested)

Comment: This is currently converting 7pm to 10am UTC, doesn't seem right.

Comment: It would work if you were in the GMT time zone like me! The return value of `.parse()` is in your local timezone. I'll have a quick think ...

Comment: Is there anyway to assume that the time is always presented in EST regardless of local time?

Comment: Updated version may still need work, e.g. add 24 * 3600 * 1000 ms to the time value to stop the time going negative. Nope, negative dates are OK.

Comment: I see, this always depends on a local offset. I was more or less hoping for a solution that does not depend on the local users time zone at all. If the code gets ported to a machine that's in UTC, this code will break. Will work on a machine that's in EST.

Comment: It does work in utc. SimpleDateFormat.format will always use the local timezone, there's no way to specify to use a different tz. The offset compensates for this. Jodatime handles tz better, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

```
val tz = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"))  
// You can also use DateTimeZone.forID(), but it requires an id in form
// like 'Europe/Paris', but I don't remember which such ID corresponds to Eastern time
val fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm a")
val fmtIn = fmt.withZone(tz)
val fmtOut = fmt.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)

val strIn = "11:30 PM"
val strOut = fmtOut.print(fmtIn.parseDateTime(strIn))
```

Easy and pretty straightforward. I'm getting `04:40 AM` for `11:30 PM`, which seems to be correct, and I'm in UTC+4 zone, so it this method works independently on local time zone.